# Flow Mapping Data?

Tags: qgis, data, flow-map

I have recently started experimenting with QGIS's flow mapping functionality. I am having trouble finding any origin/destination data online and I'm hoping someone can help?

It can be for anything. I just want to experiment with the functionality some more. I have used data from [OpenFlights](http://openflights.org/data.html) previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the recent *PLOS* [paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0155976#abstract0) by Hristova *et al.* (2016) 'The International Postal Network and Other Global Flows as Proxies for National Wellbeing'. They list several, global openly available datasets:

1. World Trade Network available from the MIT Atlas Project (https://atlas.media.mit.edu/about/data/sources/)
2. GlobalMigration Network available from the Global Migration Project (http://www.global-migration.info/)
3. IP Traceroute Network available from the DIMES Project (http://www.netdimes.org/new/?q=node/65)
4. Digital Communications Network available from the Mesh of Civilizations Project (https://sites.google.com/site/meshofcivilizations/density-measure)
5. Flight Network data available from ICAO (http://www.icao.int/Pages/default.aspx)
6. Postal Network data (available as a [Supporting Information file](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/asset?unique&id=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0155976.s003))